# Getting Error com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLException: Invalid parameter index:2 Valid range is 1 to 1 While inserting in to database?

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

i am using sql server 2005 and jdbc. Trying to insert values in to table ContentModification with below code

```
  java.sql.Date date= new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
  sql = "insert into ContentModification values(?,?)";
         pc.setString(1, space);
         pc.setDate(2, date); // line 3
     pc.executeUpdate();//line 4
```

At line 3 i am getting error  **com.jnetdirect.jsql.JSQLException: Invalid parameter index:2 Valid range is 1 to 1**
           i am not getting whats the reason for this?

My create table script is below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContentModification](
[XWC_NAME] [varchar](255) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[XWC_LASTUPDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSQLConnect(5.95) Trial license, jdk 1.6 and SQL Express 2008 your code executes successfully. This exception generally occurs when you have miss-match between the number of '?' marks in PreparedStatement and the index of setDate() / setString()

You might try changing this line :

```
 sql = "insert into ContentModification(XWC_NAME, XWC_LASTUPDATE) values(?,?)";
```